# Help with filter for wp_notify_moderator()

Tags: filters, admin, email, wp-mail

I have a case where I have multiple Administrators. Not all of them want to be notified per email when there was a comment posted or is held for moderation.

The Settings > Discussion page only allows for the control of comment moderation emails for all Admins, not for selected ones. Responsible for the emails being send is this function: http://wpseek.com/wp_notify_moderator/

Within that function there is an array stored in a variable called $emails and the first value that is being stored is **get_option('admin_email')**. The second value (email) is that of the **post author**.

At the end of the function there are some filters one of which let's you modify the $emails array and so far I got the following. But this is not working, any ideas why?

```
// Don't email webmaster for comment moderation
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'pref_dont_email_webmaster', 10, 2 );
function pref_dont_email_webmaster( $emails, $comment_id ) {
    $webmaster_email = 'name@address.xmp';
    if ( $emails[0] == $webmaster_email )
        unset($emails[0]);
    return (array) $emails;
}
```

Comment: See function [`wp_notify_moderator()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_notify_moderator) this helped me.

Answer (score 2):

`comment_moderation_recipients` filter is not in wordpress 3.6.

check link : http://wpseek.com/wp_notify_moderator/ you will find following line.

```
WORDPRESS 3.7-ALPHA-25157
```

Comment: Oh, I just assumed it'd be available in 3.6 as well. Do you know of a way to accomplish the same for lteWP3.6?